# What are algebraic sets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know, when $k$ is algebraically closed field, radical ideals of $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ correspond to affine algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ and  homogeneous ideals, except the irrelevant ideal, correspond to Projective algebraic sets in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Are there any other class of ideals which correspond to "algebraic sets" of some other space?

Comment: Irrelevant?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The homogeneous ideal $(x_0,\ldots, x_n)$ is called irrelevant ideal

Comment: Yeah, the grammar was confusing me. Fixed in the question.